# Split/explode comma delimited string field into SQL query

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, string-splitting

I have field `id_list='1234,23,56,576,1231,567,122,87876,57553,1216'`

and I want to use it to search `IN` this field:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (id_list)
```

- `id` is `integer`
- `id_list` is `varchar/text`

But in this way this doesn't work, so I need in some way to split `id_list` into select query.

What solution should I use here? I'm using the T-SQL Sybase ASA 9 database (SQL Anywhere).
But in this way this doesn't work, so I need in some way to split `id_list` into select query.

Way I see this, is to create own function with while loop through,
and each element extract based on split by delimiter position search,
then insert elements into temp table which function will return as result.

---

> **COMMENTS TO Sebastian Meine ANSWER AND HIS SOLUTIONS :**
>
> ### Sybase SQL Anywhere 9
>
> - `sa_split_list` system procedure not exist here, so it doesn't work
> - `CAST` works great
>
> ### Sybase SQL Anywhere 12
>
> - `sa_split_list` system procedure exist and works great
> - `CAST` works great
>
> ### For the Sybase SQL Anywhere 9 I have made sa_split_list system procedure replacement:
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE str_split_list(in str long varchar, in delim char(10) default ',')
> RESULT(
>   line_num integer,
>   row_value long varchar)
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE str2 long varchar;
>   DECLARE position integer;
>
>    CREATE TABLE #str_split_list (
>    line_num integer DEFAULT AUTOINCREMENT,
>    row_value long varchar null,
>    primary key(line_num));
>
>    SET str = TRIM(str)+delim;
>    SET position = CHARINDEX(delim, str);
>
>    separaterows:
>    WHILE position > 0 loop
>        SET str2 = TRIM(LEFT(str, position - 1));
>        INSERT INTO #str_split_list (row_value)
>        VALUES (str2);
>        SET str = RIGHT(str, LENGTH(str) - position);
>        SET position = CHARINDEX(delim, str);
>     end loop separaterows;
>
>    select * from #str_split_list order by line_num asc;
>
> END
> ```
>
> Execute the same way as sa_split_list:
>
> ```
> select * from str_split_list('1234,23,56,576,1231,567,122,87876,57553,1216')
> ```

Comment: The problem you are having is because your design is wrong. Don't store comma delimited lists in a database. This violates first normal form. You need a junction table with a row for each `table1_id, other_id` combination.

Comment: @JonSeigel - Does Sybase have TVFs and is the syntax the same? They were added to the product after the code base split AFAIK.

Comment: @Martin: Oops. Didn't notice the `[sybase]` tag. I have no idea; my close vote may be inappropriate. Maybe some of the *techniques* presented in there will apply?

Comment: @JonSeigel - A google indicates that there is something built in `SELECT row_value as testRecord FROM sa_split_list('A,B,C');` but I have no idea if Sybase has `CROSS APPLY` or something to use this against a column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't actually have a sybase system to test with, but according to http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/sa-split-list-sysproc.html the following solution should work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table AS T
  JOIN sa_split_list('1234,23,56,576,1231,567,122,87876,57553,1216') AS L
    ON T.id = L.row_value;
```

If the id_list is actually stored in another table (say list_table) you need to also use a `CROSS APPLY` operator (http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbusage_en11/apply-joins-joinsasp.html):

```
SELECT *
  FROM list_table AS LT
 CROSS APPLY sa_split_list(LT.id_list) L
  JOIN table T
    ON T.id = L.row_value
   AND <optional: some other condition that ties rows in list_table to rows in table, like a group membership or location>
```

This all requires that only numbers are part of these list as the split pieces will be automatically cast to the datatype of the id column. If that is not the case you can use this simpler, but slower technique:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE ','+@id_list+',' LIKE '%,'+CAST(id AS VARCHAR(20))+',%'
```

That last example assumed that the id list is in a variable @id_list. if it is in another table you can use the same `CROSS APPLY` technique from above. The additional commata make sure that the first or last entry can be matched.

Comment: I was looking for something like this and again stackexchange saved me :) Thank You for detailed answer and links!